# unresolved import 'rest_framework' after installing djangorestframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I saw similar posts created before, but nothing helped me in the end.
I am using Python 3.7.7 and my IDE is VSC.

I installed pip install djangorestframework (both in my virtualenv and outside of it)
Added '`rest_framework',` to INSTALLED_APPS. I did this by command `pip install djangorestframework`
Now, to used djangorestframework, I created a file serializer with `from rest_framework import serializers`
Now, `rest_framework` becomes underlined with the message `unresolved import 'rest_framework'`.
The whole app still works, there is no error in the console.

What would you advise me to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output of the console ?

Comment: There is no output after I type it or after I use py manage.py runserver. The only problem is rest_framework in serializer becomes underlined and says unresolved import 'rest_framework'

Comment: Are you running the code from the VScode terminal or the normal one? I also get those yellow lines sometimes but when i run the application from the terminal that comes with ubuntu it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned off and on the VSC and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like VSC doesn't see that you have rest_framework installed. I would try re-setting up your Python Interpreter. Hopefully, you're using some kind of virtual environment that you can tell VSC to look at for all your dependencies.

[Using Python Environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:%7E:text=You%20can%20also%20manually%20specify,folder%20will%20be%20searched%20for.)